# Using brackets () with LESS mixins

Tags: css, less

```
// Mixin
.text-overflow() {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Are we required to put those brackets () when we use this mixin in our code?

```
a.overflow {
  .text-overflow();
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: When calling the mixin, the braces are optional. When writing a mixin, the braces can be used if you don't want the mixin code to be output as a separate class. [Source](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-not-outputting-the-mixin).

Comment: Note: when **calling** the mixin, braces are now required (optional braces are deprecated). Same [source](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixins-feature-not-outputting-the-mixin). "Currently and historically, the parentheses in a mixin call are optional, but optional parentheses are deprecated and will be required in a future release." `.a(); // Use this to call mixin` vs `.a;  // currently works, but deprecated; don't use`

Answer (score 0):

In LESS all classes are considered mixins.  The difference between with and without parentheses is with does not output any CSS.

**Example**

```
// Less file
.no-output(){
    color: red;
} 

.output {
    color: blue;
}

// Outputs
.output {
    color: blue;
}
```